# Позиционирование ссылки поверх изображения

Tags: html, css

Я новичок в html/css. Необходимо расположить поверх блока с изображением ссылку и растянуть её зону кликабельности во весь размер блока при помощи псевдоэлемента. Получилось растянуть ссылку, но проблемы с позиционированием (ссылка выходит за пределы изображения и растягивает блок)

(background image у ссылки - это стрелочка указатель)

```css
.placement-last-div {
  position: relative;
}

.placement-more-url {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1132/PNG/512/1486348532-music-play-pause-control-go-arrow_80458.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-right: 16px;
  background-position: right center;
  transform: translate(54px, 373px);
}

.placement-last-div a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="placement-last-div">
  <img src="https://all-aforizmy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/941b9f47128f22e22ed090bf98e71939.jpeg" alt="Все варианты">
  <a href="#" class="placement-more-url">
        Посмотреть все варианты
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предложу вам немного переделать структуру, может такой вариант будет лучше для вас.

```css
.placement-last-div {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://all-aforizmy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/941b9f47128f22e22ed090bf98e71939.jpeg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.placement-more-url {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.placement-more-url::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1132/PNG/512/1486348532-music-play-pause-control-go-arrow_80458.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  top: 12px;
  right: -20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="placement-last-div">
  <p class="placement-more-url">
    Посмотреть все варианты
  </p>
</a>
```

P.S: ссылка внизу `align-items: flex-end;`

```css
.placement-last-div {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://all-aforizmy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/941b9f47128f22e22ed090bf98e71939.jpeg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: cover;
}

.placement-more-url {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.placement-more-url::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1132/PNG/512/1486348532-music-play-pause-control-go-arrow_80458.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  top: 12px;
  right: -20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="placement-last-div">
  <p class="placement-more-url">
    Посмотреть все варианты
  </p>
</a>
```

Comment: а можно ли как-то расположить ссылку снизу, а не по центру?

Comment: @unpromissing можно конечно, добавил в ответ